# Gas Cost of a Single Function

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

how can I check the gas cost of a single function in my smart contract?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web3 has a [estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#estimategas) method which can be used to get the amount of the gas used. Then either use web3's **getGasPrice** or use an external service, like https://ethgasstation.info/api/ethgasAPI.json, to get the current price of a gas unit.
The final step is to do the math: gas cost = estimated gas * gas price (be aware of WEI/GWEI conversion)

Comment: good answer but you should take care because the estimated gas depends on the specific input, another input could cost more gas.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the response.